# ios parse issue nstimer tutorial

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have followed the tutorial:

[www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/a-simple-stopwatch-for-iphone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/a-simple-stopwatch-for-iphone/)

and I get 1 error and 1 warning, both on the same line 71

```
for (int i = [timeArray count] – 1; i >= 0; i–) {
```

**error – a parse issue Expected )
warning – Unused entity issue Expression result unused**

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this,

```
for (int i = [timeArray count] – 1; i >= 0; i–) {
```

to,

```
for (int i = [timeArray count] – 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Compiler is saying that it is not able to parse the character '–'. If it is not able to recognize the for loop syntax and parse it, it will throw this error.

Answer (score 1):

As ACB mentioned, the expression needs to be i-- instead of i-.

Just a couple of notes - Douglas Crawford actually recommends to avoid using  -- and ++ in favor of doing i -= 1.  While a smidgen verbose, there is no room for doubt over what it actually does versus something like

```
int example = --i + b;
```

may confuse some to the value of i after the end of the expression.

Also, as a minor optimization, you should put the size of the array in a local value as opposed to calling [timeArray count] every loop iteration

```
int timeArraySize = [timeArray count] - 1;
for (int i = timeArraySize; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
```

Hope that helps!